# Prove that there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $P(c)P'(c) = 0$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. Suppose $a$ and $b$ are roots of $P(x)$ with $a < b$. Prove that there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $P(c)P'(c) = 0$.

**Attempt:**

Let $P(x) = (x-a)(x-b)R(x)$. Then $P'(x)=(x^2-(a+b)x+ab)R'(x) + R(x)(2x-(a+b))$ and thus $P(c)P'(c) = (c^2-(a+b)c+ab)((c^2-(a+b)c+ab)R'(c)+R(c)(2c-(a+b))$ and thus if $c^2-(a+b)c+ab = 0$, then $a = c$ or $b = c$ so there are no solutions there. On the other hand we must have that $(c^2-(a+b)c+ab)R'(c)+R(c)(2c-(a+b) = 0$. How do I show the existence of such a $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=P^2(x)$, $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Apply Rolle.

Answer (score 2):

It's just Rolle's theorem, which says there's a $c \in (a,b)$ with $P'(c) = 0$. So automatically $P(c)P'(c) = 0$ too.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $P$ hasn't a root in $(a,b)$, and then that $P$ is all positive or negative, suppose positive. Because $P'$ is a polynomial, is continuous. If $P'(x)>(<)0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, $P$ is strictly crescent (decrescent) and $P(b)\neq 0$. If exists $d,e\in (a,b)$ such that $P'(d)<0$ and $P'(d)>0$, by Bolzano the problem ends.